# Translate coordinate system in scatterplot

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

How do I make axes position at the centre of the scatterplot in nvd3 ? In order to show all the quadrants of the scatter plot and origin being at the the mid value of x-range and y-range for data being plotted.

Comment: AFAIK NVD3 doesn't provide enough flexibility to let you do this. You could however move the axis containers after they have been created.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can you please explain using translate on a scatterplot axis with a jsfiddle?

Comment: You would do something like `d3.select(".nv-y.nv-axis").attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")` and similarly for the x axis.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did try that but I couldn't get it to work correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/kamalreddy88/W3T5m/ http://jsfiddle.net/kamalreddy88/s2PmE/5/

Comment: Hmm, looks like you would need to modify the source code of NVD3. Or do it in plain D3 to start with.